# Using await hinders the process of program

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8

I'm coding an app for Windows 8 which needs to get the HTML of a particular site. It was working well  when i coded it into the button event which is in the MainPage. However, when I tried to do it in my class 'Band':

```
        public Band(String Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        GetHtmlDocument();
        GenerateId();
        GetAlbumDocument();
        GenerateLogo();
        GeneratePhoto();
        CreateAlbumList();
    }

    private async void GetHtmlDocument()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler as HttpMessageHandler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://www.metal-archives.com/bands/" + Name) };
        var r = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
        string html = null;
        if (r.IsSuccessStatusCode) html = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(html);
        DocumentBand = document;
    }
```

It came to

```
var r = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
```

line and then proceed from the `GenerateId()` method as it is in the constructor. But in order to process `GenerateId()` method, `GetHtmlDocument()` method must be finished. What should i do in this situation?

My main language is Java and I'm very new to the C#, so there may huge coding or naming mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
    public Band(String Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public async Task Init()
    {
        await GetHtmlDocument();
        GenerateId();
        GetAlbumDocument();
        GenerateLogo();
        GeneratePhoto();
        CreateAlbumList();
    }

    // Note Task Return type
    private async Task GetHtmlDocument()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler as HttpMessageHandler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://www.metal-archives.com/bands/" + Name) };
        var r = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
        string html = null;
        if (r.IsSuccessStatusCode) html = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(html);
        DocumentBand = document;
    }
```

From your code, you would have to call init separately:

```
 Band band = new Band("name");
 await band.Init();
```

The reason for having a separate `Init()` function is because `async` and `await` cannot be used inside of the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Although your function GetHtmlDocument has an async signature it't not called regarding that signature.

You call client.GetAsync() in your function. That will give control back to the calling function, in this case the constrcutor of Band without waiting for the result.

Changing the call to

```
await GetHtmlDocument()
```

Should bring things in sync.

Comment: I did what you said;  `var r = await GetHtmlDocument();`, but now it gives another error **Explore_a_Metal_Band.Band.GetHtmlDocument() does not return a Task and cannot be awaited. Consider changing it to return Task.**. Can you elaborate it a little bit ?

Comment: This will not work because the call to `GetHtmlDocument` is in the constructor. The `async` keyword is not supported there (in the constructor), which means `await` cannot be used there either.

Comment: `await` can not be used in a constructor so it didn't worked. Am i wrong? Can you elaborate it a little bit ?